# How to insert HTML symbol after Bootstrap panel-heading in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, html-entities

I'm adding a `>` symbol to the end of a bootstrap panel so that it will expand out the panel when toggled.

But when I add the [HTML character entity](https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/) `&gt;` for a greater than symbol, to the css style for this transformation. it renders the HTML code for the symbol rather than the symbol:

[image]

The complete example I'm taking this from is located here:

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/faq-example

How can you render a HTML special character inside a panel using CSS?

This is my attempt at the styl which does rotate the characters as expected but the symbol isn't shown:

```
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
        font-family: Verdana;
        content: "&gt"; /* "play" icon */
        float: right;
        color: #F58723;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 22px;
        /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to down arrow */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow right the link you provide us, there's a code for CSS. Here you are working on CSS and not HTML. Shouldn't you use the CSS code instead of the html one `content: '\003e';`? Just a guess, I have never done this.

If it doesn't work, you may have to use `:after` so the code won't get overwrite.

I have test this this way and it worked. Hope it helps ;)

```
h1:after {
    content: '\003e';
}
```